# Help calculating witch attack with prehensile hair

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon, witch

Level 8
BAB 4
STR 7 (-2)
INT 26 (+8)

Hex: [Prehensile hair](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su/)

Even though it is listed as a secondary natural attack, I would just use the hair to attack as a standard action. How would I apply the STR mod as it’s only form of natural attack? Is this how I would calculate the attack modifier and damage?

Attack: +12 (BAB 4 + INT 8)
Damage: 1d3+12 (INT 8*1.5)

This wording from the universal monster rules might be relevant:

> If a creature has only one natural attack, it is always made using the
>   creature’s full base attack bonus and adds 1-1/2 times the creature’s
>   Strength bonus on damage rolls. This increase does not apply if the
>   creature has multiple attacks but only takes one. If a creature has
>   only one type of attack, but has multiple attacks per round, that
>   attack is treated as a primary attack, regardless of its type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can use your Prehensile Hair as a Primary Natural attack if its your only Natural attack.

While its true that Prehensile Hair references that it's a Secondary Natural Attack, this is a formality *not an overwrite*. It's only indicating that because it falls under 'Other' on the Natural Attack table, it is typically a Secondary natural attack. This *only* applies if you have other Natural attacks such as Claws or a Bite, or when using manufactured weapons as well (in which case *all* Natural attacks become Secondary).

[The Universal Monster Rule](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) is the more specific rule in this instance, and does allow you to make a BAB attack for STRx1.5 (INTx1.5 in this case) attack *if* you don't posses Claws, Bite, etc (as well as do not attack with manufactured weapons).

*Note* In a strange caveat, even *possessing* another Natural attack negates this benefit, whether or not you're using them.

The nail in the coffin is that Prehensile Hair *does not* say that it can *only* be a Secondary Natural attack. It *only* says what it is. As with the many creatures that have Secondary Natural attacks that fall under the referenced UMR, the UMR *alters* that 'normal' state. Additionally, if you're forgoing the ability to cast a spell, attack with a weapon, and any other Natural attacks, it's fair to allow you to deal 1d3+INTx1.5.

Comment: That's what I intended to say. I'll check my phrasing to clarify

Answer (score 2):

> [Secondary attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks) are made using the creature’s base attack bonus –5 and add only 1/2 the creature’s Strength bonus on damage rolls.

And, using [Prehensile hair](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su/), a witch:

> can manipulate her hair as if it were a limb with a Strength score equal to her Intelligence score. Her hair has reach 10 feet, and she can use it as a secondary natural attack that deals 1d3 points of damage (1d2 for a Small witch).

So, being a secondary natural attack, the hair attack would be:

Attack: +7 (+4 BAB, +8 INT-as-STR, -5 secondary attack)
Damage: 1d3 + 4 (8 INT-as-STR * 0.5)

Note, however, that a witch

> with natural attacks and attacks made with weapons can use both as part of a full attack action
>   ([Natural Attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks))

So that same witch could also attack with, say, a dagger at +2 (+4 BAB, -2 STR) for 1d4 - 2 (STR) in the same round as the hair attack (and, of course, could use feats like [Weapon Finesse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat-final/) on the dagger attack).

Comment: I haven't finished researching yet, but [this Paizo thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mhfx&page=2?Prehensile-Hair-skill-use) may be of interest. (This answer was my thinking originally as well.)

Comment: I added something from the universal monster rules. Does that affect your answer at all?

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I don't think it changes the RAW: the quoted rule is the general rule and Prehensile tail is more specific, which means it wins out. This GM would easily accept the hair being used as a primary natural attack if no other attacks were made in a round, but I think RAW's precedence rules mean prehensile hair's description wins and it's "stuck" at secondary.